# Set html table to right of another table

Tags: html, css

I want to set an html table to the right of another table within a div. If I just do

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
             //stuff
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
              //stuff
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

it lists one table above the other, I need them left to right to align a user control and I can't fit it into one table because the rows being different heights would not work. How to I make tables flow left to right instead of top to bottom in a div?

Comment: `float: left` ?

Comment: @davidp04 Why not table inside table? see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `float:direction` or `display:inline-block` CSS property

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/v10hqa66/

Comment: I really like this because the fiddle site lets me play around with the html

Comment: i'm glad i could help, have your time playing with html and find the solution which best fits your needs!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your containing div to `display: flex;`.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you because you may be new here. This should be placed as a comment. (You have sufficient rep for that.) Or improve your answer since it lacks quality.

Comment: @KarelG I don't see why a valid answer should be given as a comment (it's not commenting on the question), simply because it's short and to the point. It's a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can put table inside table. I would prefer following way:

```html
   <div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        table one
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        table two
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ad an ID to one of the tables and then in the css, float the table left.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
             //stuff
           </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="left">
        <tr>
            <td>
              //stuff
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Put this in the head:

```
<style>
#left{
float:left;
}
</style>
```